# Почему оно не работает

Tags: javascript, html, анимация

```
//Этот код должен двигать элемент "brick" в соответствие с закон физики при броске вверх. 
//Мы получаем на вход элемент, с id=v0


      brick.onclick = function() {
  
      let start = Date.now();
      var inputvv = document.getElementById('v0');
      var t = Number(inputvv.value);

      var sum = 0; 
      let delta = 0; 
      var t0;

      let timer = setInterval(function() {
        let timePassed = Date.now() - start;
        delta=v0-9.81*t0;//Это мы вычисляем каждый раз длину, на которое должен сместиться brick за этот проход цикла
          t0=t+0.02;
          brick.style.left = sum + 'px';
          sum += delta;    
          if (t0 > t) clearInterval(timer);
      }, 20)
```

Comment: потому что вы не сильно понимаете, что вы написали, вот, например, что такое `v0` в присвоении значения `delta`? должны быть ошибки в консоли браузера, к тому же, вы умножаете на `t0` в той же строчке, а `t0` в тот момент времени будет иметь значение `undefined`

Answer (score -1):

```html
<button id=brick style="position: absolute; top: 200px"> жми </button>
<script>
let h = h1 = parseInt(brick.style.top); // 200
let u = -100; // начальное ускорение
let k = 3; // высота полёта
let step = 0.03; // скорость полёта
brick.onclick = () => {
    brick.innerText = " лечу ";
    let timer = setInterval( () => {
        brick.style.top = h + "px";
        h += u * step; // как меняется высота
        u += 9.81 * step * k; // как меняется ускорение
        if(h > h1){
            clearInterval(timer);
            brick.innerText = " жми ";
            u = -100;
        }
    }, 20);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const brickNode = document.querySelector('#brick');
const hInitial = brickNode.computedStyleMap().get('top').value;
const uInitial = -100;
let h = hInitial // 170
let u = uInitial; // начальное ускорение
let k = 3; // высота полёта
let step = 0.03; // скорость полёта

brickNode.onclick = () => {
  brickNode.innerText = 'лечу';
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
};

function anim(nowTime) {
  if (anim.thenTime === undefined) anim.thenTime = nowTime;
  const deltaTime = nowTime - anim.thenTime;

  brick.style.top = h + 'px';
  h += u * step; // как меняется высота
  u += 9.81 * step * k; // как меняется ускорение
  if (h > hInitial) {
    h = hInitial;
    brick.style.top = h + 'px';
    brickNode.innerText = 'жми';
    u = uInitial;
    cancelAnimationFrame(anim);
  } else {
    requestAnimationFrame(anim)
  }
}
```

```css
#brick {
  position: absolute;
  top: 170px;
}
```

```html
<button id="brick">жми</button>
```